# Динамический id у элемента в JavaScript

Tags: webforms, javascript, html

Есть функция:

```
function validate_form (myElementID) {
......
if (document."formm"+myElementID.name.value == "ваша почта"; .....)
......
....
}
```

В чем суть вопроса. У меня на странице куча форм. В функцию передается номер формы.
Задача - передать в условие номер формы. Перепробовал разные конструкции:
"formm"+myElementID
formm+myElementID
("formm"+myElementID)

итд
ничего не подходит)
как сделать правильно, подскажите!) спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, так?

```
document["formm"+myElementID].name.value
```

---

Возможно, правильнее и кросс-браузернее будет

```
document.getElementById("formm"+myElementID).name.value
```

— попробуйте.

Comment: супер! все работает! спасибо!

Comment: @jackair: пожалуйста! тем не менее, посмотрите на обновление ответа.